# Angularjs using Rowspan in Collections

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have collections of data coming from JSON request.. that i want to display with row span using angular.. but its not yet working properly..  hopefully you can help me with this.

```
$scope.data = [
    {
        order_number: "A-0001",
        name: "computer 01-01",
        status: 'new'
    },
    {
        order_number: "A-0002",
        name: "computer 02-01",
        status: 'new'
    },
    {
        order_number: "A-0001",
        name: "computer 01-02",
        status: 'new'
    },
    {
        order_number: "A-0003",
        name: "computer 03-01",
        status: 'check'
    },
    {
        order_number: "A-0001",
        name: "computer 01-03",
        status: 'new'
    },
    {
        order_number: "A-0003",
        name: "computer 03-02",
        status: 'check'
    }

];
```

I want my collections to display in a table like this.

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
      <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>Order Number</th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Status</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         <tr>
                <td rowspan="3">A-0001</td>
                <td>01-01</td>
                <td>new</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
                <td>01-02</td>
                <td>new</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
                <td>01-03</td>
                <td>new</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
                <td>A-0002</td>
                <td>02-01</td>
                <td>new</td>
         </tr>

      </tbody>
  </table>
```

[demo plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3rXnb6d1SSvIfPcPfwx4?p=preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a true angular solution, you shouldn't need javascript to alter the dom.  Angular's goal is to have the data itself dictate how controls are rendered.

Are you able to change your data structure?  I find it a bit odd that you have id's that aren't unique.  I took the liberty of changing it so that each order has a set of sub_orders, which consist of the name and status.

Here's a working plunker with an altered data structure.
http://plnkr.co/edit/lpfAJPejfVGaJqB8f6HR?p=preview

Data structure:

```
$scope.data = [
     {
       order_number: "A-0001",
       sub_orders: [
         {
           name: "computer 01-01",
           status: "new"
         },
         {
           name: "computer 01-02",
           status: "new"
         },
         {
           name: "computer 01-03",
           status: "new"
         }
         ]
     },
     {
       order_number: "A-0002",
       sub_orders: [
         {
           name: "computer 02-01",
           status: "new"
         }
         ]
     },
     {
       order_number: "A-0003",
       sub_orders: [
         {
           name: "computer 03-01",
           status: "new"
         },
         {
           name: "computer 03-02",
           status: "new"
         }
         ]
     }

    ];
```

Here's the angular code for rendering the table:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
      <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>Order Number</th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Status</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody ng-repeat="order in data">
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="{{order.sub_orders.length + 1}}">{{order.order_number}}</td>
        </tr>
         <tr ng-repeat="suborder in order.sub_orders">
           <td>{{suborder.name}}</td>
           <td>{{suborder.status}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: thank you for your solution.. yup your right, better to restructured my data.. and i didnt put my id in my example.. bcoz i just want togroup it by orders using rowspan

Comment: By the way. What if i want the status to have rowspan same as order number? Is that possible?

Comment: It's possible, but it wouldn't be very clean.  You'd basically have to use Sonaryr's solution, where you order the suborder's by the status, and use a function to determine the rowspan.  Off the top of my head, I can't think of a data structure that would allow this.

Comment: You can change the data structure further, so it's a hierarchy of order numbers containing statuses that contain names, but I wouldn't really recommend it.  Your data structure would begin to lose it's meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Just made a quick and dirty solution to your problem using the data provided

http://plnkr.co/edit/fvVh73sXfIRLHw42Q2XM?p=preview

I ordered the data with ng-repeat and orderBy

```
ng-repeat="item in data | orderBy: 'order_number'"
```

And then using functions I checked if we needed a rowspan or not.

A Better solution for you would be to refactor the data,like MaskedTwilight's solution suggests, so that your order are already grouped per order number and that your items are a subcollection of this order. That whay you can reduce the code and watchers.

Comment: this solution is very straight forward.. this one works too.. but what if... i want to have a rowspan for order_number and status?.. or other column with same value to group..

Comment: Like I said, it is a quick and dirty solution, not perfect, for your changes you will need to refactor your data as MaskedTwilight answer.